# What is the Lift-way to convert Box[Elem] to LiftResponse?

Tags: scala, lift

I came across this issue already a couple of times and I wonder what the Lift-way is to perform such an action. Of course I could do my own error handling etc. but basically I wonder how I can turn a Box[Elem] into a LiftResponse. Ideally an XmlResponse of course.

The scenario is that I am using the RestHelper for an API and I have a function that returns me a Box[Elem]. I would like to make use of the async support.

The error I get is that Box[Elem] (or Box[NodeSeq], Box[Node]) cannot be converted to LiftResponse. However the exact same code without using RestContinuation works.

Note: I do not want Lift to do any template processing logic. Just output the XML the same way it would happen without using RestContinuation.

```
val userId = S.param("userId") map { _.toInt }

RestContinuation.async {
  reply => {
    reply(
      for {
        user <- userRepo.select(userId) ?~ "No such user." ~> 404
      } yield {
         <user>
           <name>{user.name}</name>
         </user>
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an `implicit` declaration missing. You can bring this implicit (`implicit def canNodeToResponse(in: Box[Seq[Node]]): LiftResponse` in scope by mixing-in the `trait` `XMLApiHelper` in the surrounding class.

Comment: What I am missing though is this "object creation impossible, since method createTag in trait XMLApiHelper of type (in: scala.xml.NodeSeq)scala.xml.Elem is not defined". What should I use for createTag? Why is it there, and why is every responsed wrapped with it?

Comment: `createTag` is used to specify the root tag of your XML api. You’d usually just wrap the `NodeSeq` in some other tag: `def createTag(in: NodeSeq) = <myapi>{ in }</myapi>`.

Comment: Okay, that is not what I am looking for. There is no <myapi>{in}</myapi> around all the tags. So is there an option to get the same behaviour as I would get with RestHelper which can for instance handle both JSON and Xml?

Comment: The reason create tag is necessary is that a NodeSeq may not be something that can be directly returned.  It could be a scala.xml.Group for instance.  If you are only returning Elements you can cast your NodeSeq, or better yet pattern match on it and wrap it only if it is not an Elem.